# How to access IloIntArray elements while in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++builder, cplex

Hi StackOverFlow fellows,

I'm solving MILP models in C++ with CPLEX via the Concert Technology library which encodes variable and parameter arrays respectively into `IloVarArray` and `IloArray` objects. I have already read the numerous questions on how to access ordinary arrays on Visual Studio in debugger mode.

However, querying for `array,i-1`, on the *Immediate Window*, if you want to access the value stored on the `i-th` position of an `IloIntArray array` is not very useful as you get a highly informational message:

```
IloArray<__int64>: {_impl=0x0000028c514ad968 {_max=4 _sizeof=8 _size=3 ...} }
```

Which, as you can see contains a single useful piece of information, the array size e.g. `array` contains three elements on its first dimension, as it might contain several. It doesn't even prompts an error if trying to index beyond the array bounds!

But you don't get to access the values in the array unless you include a great deal of `cout` instructions, and potentially a bunch of `for` loops, as well as rebuilding your project a million times which is extremely time-consuming even in moderate size models.

So, can we actually access an `IloArray` element while on debugger without much hassle, or is `cout` my only available option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do know that classes like IloIntArray are actually just 'handle' classes? These contain little (or nothing) beyond a pointer (usually called '_impl') to an instance of a corresponding 'implementation' class. They were just defined to make the syntax for using these classes look cleaner (e.g. you don't need to keep dereferencing pointers etc).

I did once have a set of Visual Studio definitions for changing how the debugger displayed instances of these classes (see e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730838(v=vs.80).aspx) but that seems to have got lost and I can't find a copy any more.

Later versions of VS use a different method: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/07/12/debugger-type-visualizers-for-c-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: Thank you so much! The Concert Technology is indeed very useful in general. And I do acknowledge is a much cleaner and easy way of building and solving models as well as facilitating the access to the CPLEX optimization process, but it takes a while to get used to it in order to use it effectively. Thanks for your help @TimChippingtonDerrick